# Trick ComboBox into thinking its' dropdown is open when it's not

Tags: c#-4.0, combobox, custom-controls, overriding, dropdownbox

I found a control that displays a CheckedListBox for the dropdown of a combobox. I like this but I want to improve upon it. I want to perfectly replicate the behavior of the standard combobox like so:

When the user clicks the combobox the dropdown (CheckedListBox) opens.

When the user clicks inside the dropdown they have no problem checking multiple options.

When the user clicks the ComboBox again the DropDown hides.

When the user clicks off the combobox (ANYWHERE, be it on a control or just the form), the DropDown gets hidden.

I found on P/Invoke.net the PostMessage function in the User32.DLL library that allows you to send a message to the ComboBox using the CB_SHOWDROPDOWN (0x014F) message to force it to immediately close the native DropDown.

The problem in doing so is that it will automatically force call the OnDropDownClosed function of the base ComboBox control. This I would not care about but it stops the natural feeling of the control (for me at least) in that if you do some trickery with it to keep your custom dropdown open, it still stays open when you click off the control (because the ComboBox thinks it's dropdown is closed already).

That is the behavior I want to avoid. I want the ComboBox to think that it's DropDown is still open when it's not (until the user either clicks the combobox to close it or clicks off the control).

Also, the problem I was experiencing before just letting it open the native combobox dropdown was that when I went to click on the custom dropdown, the ComboBox fires the OnDropDownClosed function and (seeing as how I override that method to hide the custom dropdown), my dropdown is hidden.

So...

How do I override the OnDropDown method to open up a custom custom dropdown that, when clicked, will not fire the OnDropDownClosed method, I guess, is the short way of asking the question.

Comment: did you try something?

Comment: I tried overriding the OnDropDown method of the ComboBox to do Child.Show(this) (Child is the custom dropdown). It works great except that when I click the Child the ComboBox fires the OnDropDownClosed method, which, again, I override to hide the Child.